# How to loop through array while using agg and apply np.average

Tags: python, pandas

I need help about using a list of columns to apply to apply " np.average " like presented below :

```
def answer_three():
    Top15 = answer_one()

    selected_col = ['2006', '2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015']

    avgGDP = Top15.groupby('Country').agg({"list of columns" :  np.average})
    return avgGDP
answer_three()
```

Can anyone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: You can create a dictionary and apply that dictionary

Comment: `Top15.groupby('Country')[selected_col].mean()`?

Comment: Thank you  for this  help. But I have forgotten something which is that, the return object must be a series not a DF. When applying this `Top15.groupby('Country')[selected_col].mean() ` I get a DF.

Comment: can you please add an expected output in your question, do you want the resulting series to only contain averages or to include the countries as well?

Comment: Yes   of course with countries !

Comment: what does your expected output look like? Are you just trying to add a new column to Top15 or are you trying to create separate arrays for each country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a series means for multiple columns for each country, first `groupby`, second,select the columns, thrid, calculate the `mean`, and fourth, `stack`:

```
selected_col = ['2006', '2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015']
avgGDP = Top15.groupby('Country')[selected_col].mean().stack()
```